EF Core LINQ projection with nested extracted logic does not work
I'm trying to extract projection logic for EF Core LINQ queries into separate methods to make the code cleaner or reuse the code for different projections?
There is a similar post for reusing code at Can I reuse code for selecting a custom DTO object for a child property with EF Core?, but the selected answer uses additional libraries and the question was about to use a call like Select(Model.AsDto), which encapsulates the lambda.
I want to use a simple solution and don't want to remove the lambda expression. I just want to extract the mapping part that creates the new object, like  (danceCoverImage, image) => Mappings.MapToImageItemResponse(danceCoverImage, image)).
This works fine for one nested level, but not for two as shown in the example below.
I have this sample projection that returns location data with nested cover images. The image URI, width, and height is pulled with a join from the image collection.
List<LocationMLResponse> Locations;

var query = dbContext.Location.AsNoTracking()
           .Select(location => new LocationMLResponse(
            location.Id.Value,
            location.Name.ToStringDictionary(),
            location.CoverImages
                .Join(dbContext.Image.AsNoTracking(),
                danceCoverImage => danceCoverImage.ImageId,
                image => image.Id,
                (danceCoverImage, image) => new ImageItemResponse(
                    danceCoverImage.ImageId.Value,
                    danceCoverImage.DisplayOrder,
                    danceCoverImage.Language == null ? null : danceCoverImage.Language.Tag,
                    danceCoverImage.ScreenSize == null ? null : danceCoverImage.ScreenSize.Value,
                    danceCoverImage.FocusPointX,
                    danceCoverImage.FocusPointY,
                    image.Uri.ToString(),
                    image.MetaData.Width,
                    image.MetaData.Height
                )).ToList(),
            location.Address.MapToDto(),
            location.Created,
            location.LastModified,
            location.Version
            ));

Locations = await query.ToListAsync();

I tried to extracted methods for the mapping:
var query = dbContext.Location.AsNoTracking()
           .Select(location => MapToLocationResponse.MLResponse(dbContext, location));

internal static class MapToLocationResponse
{
    public static LocationMLResponse MLResponse(VCDbContext dbContext, Location location)
    {
        return new LocationMLResponse(
            location.Id.Value,
            location.Name.ToStringDictionary(),
            location.CoverImages
                .Join(dbContext.Image.AsNoTracking(),
                danceCoverImage => danceCoverImage.ImageId,
                image => image.Id,
                (danceCoverImage, image) => Mappings.MapToImageItemResponse(danceCoverImage, image)).ToList(),
            location.Address.MapToDto(),
            location.Created,
            location.LastModified,
            location.Version
            );
    }
}

internal static partial class Mappings
{
    public static ImageItemResponse MapToImageItemResponse(ImageItem imageItem, Image image)
    {
        return new ImageItemResponse(
            imageItem.ImageId.Value,
            imageItem.DisplayOrder,
            imageItem.Language == null ? null : imageItem.Language.ToString(),
            imageItem.ScreenSize == null ? null : imageItem.ScreenSize.ToString(),
            imageItem.FocusPointX,
            imageItem.FocusPointY,
            image.Uri.ToString(),
            image.MetaData.Width,
            image.MetaData.Height
        );
    }
}

This code creates the following query:
SELECT [l].[LocationId], [l].[Created], [l].[CreatedBy], [l].[CreatedInNameOf], [l].[LastModified], [l].[LastModifiedBy], [l].[LastModifiedInNameOf], [l].[Name], [l].[TId], [l].[Version], [l].[Address_City], [l].[Address_CountryId], [l].[Address_CountryName], [l].[Address_DeliveryInstruction], [l].[Address_State], [l].[Address_Street], [l].[Address_StreetAffix], [l].[Address_StreetNumber], [l].[Address_ZipCode], [l0].[TId], [l0].[DisplayOrder], [l0].[FocusPointX], [l0].[FocusPointY], [l0].[ImageId], [l0].[Language], [l0].[LocationId], [l0].[ScreenSize]
FROM [VC].[Location] AS [l]
LEFT JOIN [VC].[LocationCoverImage] AS [l0] ON [l].[LocationId] = [l0].[LocationId]
ORDER BY [l].[LocationId]

The join to the Image table and the selection of the image fields is missing.
I tried mapping with only one nesting:
 List<LocationMLResponse> Locations;

 var query = dbContext.Location.AsNoTracking()//.AsSplitQuery()
            .Select(location => new LocationMLResponse(
             location.Id.Value,
             location.Name.ToStringDictionary(),
             location.CoverImages
                 .Join(dbContext.Image.AsNoTracking(),
                 danceCoverImage => danceCoverImage.ImageId,
                 image => image.Id,
                 (danceCoverImage, image) => Mappings.MapToImageItemResponse(danceCoverImage, image)).ToList(),
             location.Address.MapToDto(),
             location.Created,
             location.LastModified,
             location.Version
             ));

 Locations = await query.ToListAsync();

This works. The projection creates the same query as the full projection on top.
(As a note, there is a general issue with the created query that I posted in the EF Core GitHub issues.
Is this a problem with EF Core in general or is it just connected to the join? Is it possible to use the nested call or is it required to use expressions for this?

EF Core version: 8.0.8
Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Target framework: NET 8.0
Operating system: Win 11
Visual Studio 2022 17.11.4

It's better to opt for one of these third-party libraries. EF can't analyze the compiled method body to generate optimal SQL as you might expect, though we can simulate this behavior using an interceptor. Keep in mind that SQL is constructed from expressions.

(danceCoverImage, image) => Mappings.MapToImageItemResponse(danceCoverImage, image)) and similar are method call expressions.
The content of MapToImageItemResponse is a black box. It is compiled and can't be easily inspected and translated into SQL.
The right way to make a reusable piece of mapping is to define a method that would return exactly what you have in case of inlined lambda - a projection linq expression.
Expression<Func<ImageItem, Image, ImageItemResponse>> GetImageItemResponseMapping() 
{
    return (imageItem, image) => new ImageItemResponse(
                    imageItem.ImageId.Value,
                    imageItem.DisplayOrder,
                    imageItem.Language == null ? null : imageItem.Language.Tag,
                    imageItem.ScreenSize == null ? null : imageItem.ScreenSize.Value,
                    imageItem.FocusPointX,
                    imageItem.FocusPointY,
                    image.Uri.ToString(),
                    image.MetaData.Width,
                    image.MetaData.Height);
}

Then
location.CoverImages
                 .AsQueryable()
                 .Join(dbContext.Image.AsNoTracking(),
                 danceCoverImage => danceCoverImage.ImageId,
                 image => image.Id,
                 GetImageItemResponseMapping())

If done properly, it should work regardless of the amount of nesting levels.

I expected EF Core to analyze a static method that is a static mapping. I understand now that it needs to be an expression, but I don't understand how your code should work. CoverImage is a property of an entity and not a type. Therefore I get a compile error. The type Image is used in various objects, but not all are named CoverImage.
I additionally get error CS1539 (Delegate Func does not take 2 arguments).

I got the Expression working stating all three types:
public static Expression<Func<ImageItem, Image, ImageItemResponse>> GetImageItemResponseMapping()

The code resulted in error CS1929 at location.CoverImages right before .Join. The solution from the other post was to use 'AsQueryable()': location.CoverImages.AsQueryable(). Can you update your answer to correct the code then I can accept it as answer.
